# AEM 6.2 data-sly-resource resourceType is not set on imported component

Tags: javascript, aem, sightly, htl

In AEM 6.2, I want to import a component using 'data-sly-resource' like so:

```
<div id="email" data-sly-resource="${'text' @ resourceType='/libs/foundation/components/form/text'}"></div>
```

In this code, resourceType is used to reference the path to the component, and thus not set as a property on the imported component.

If I use this, the imported component does not have a resourceType defined. How can I define the resourceType of the imported component?

Comment: There is a conflict in your question. In headline you wrote AWM 6.2 and in your question you wrote AEM6.3. For clarification: Do work on AEM6.2 or AEM 6.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a valid resource type. The resource type of the component defined at `/libs/foundation/components/form/text` is `foundation/components/form/text`. Given this resource type, Sling will find the relevant scripts in `/libs/foundation/components/form/text` or an overlay somewhere in `/apps` if one is present.